# ignorecase messing up visual mode for vim in OS X Lion?

Tags: vim, osx-lion

I'm seeing some behavior that looks like a bug in vim in OS X Lion. If I set `ignorecase`, then visual mode (`v` in command/normal mode) automatically moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. If I unset `ignorecase` again, visual mode works as it should.

When I try the exact same `.vimrc` on a Solarix machine with an older vim (7.0.162), everything works as it should.

I see the problem with MacVim (vim 7.3.390) when it's run in a terminal (by symlinking `vim` to `mvim`) and when it's run as a Cocoa app. I also see the problem when I run the vim that was included in OS X (`/usr/bin/vim`, version 7.3). Tried to look for something in the [list of known vim problems](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/todo.html) but couldn't find it there.

Comment: Take a look at what return the `:verbose map v` command. Like you, I'm running Vim 7.3, compiled from source, on Mac OS 10.7.4 and everything has always worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem wasn't with vim at all, but with the plugin bisect.com. When I dropped that, everything worked just fine.